# How do I generate an xPub using stellar SDK?

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, ed25519

How do I generate an xPub using stellar SDK ? 
could anyone show me the format of a stellar extended public key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't generate `xPub` for Stellar keys according to [SEP-0005](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0005.md). Stellar is using [SLIP-0010](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0010.md) (as defined in [SEP-0005](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0005.md)). From "Master key generation" section:

> ed25519 curve the private keys are no longer multipliers for the group generator; instead the hash of the private key is the multiplier. For this reason, our scheme for ed25519 does not support public key derivation and uses the produced hashes directly as private keys.

There are proposals for generating HD keys with a possibility to generate extended public keys for `ed25519` like:

- https://chain.com/docs/1.2/protocol/specifications/chainkd
- https://cardanolaunch.com/assets/Ed25519_BIP.pdf

However these are not supported by Stellar.

#### Why Stellar selected [SLIP-0010](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0010.md) over other solutions?

[SLIP-0010](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0010.md) is supported in hardware wallets like [Ledger](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/) or [Trezor](https://trezor.io/). We wanted a solution that is compatible with them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer! However, both links in this post are dead, is anyone able to update them to new locations?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no API to generate it from Stellar SDK

This link help you to generate xPub
https://iancoleman.io/bip39/?#english

Comment: That tool doesnt have stellar !

Comment: I think stellar does not support xPub